# jquery: how to set download attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the download attribute on a link tag using jquery.
In general I am using

```
<a type="button" id="pdf_modal_button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/download/x.pdf" download target="_blank">Download</a>
```

which downloads the pdf fine.

The problem arises when I generate a link:

```
<a type="button" id="pdf_modal_button" class="btn btn-primary" href=/download/>Download</a>
```

and then try to update the link with jquery:

```
    var _href = $('#pdf_modal_button').attr("href");
    $('#pdf_modal_button').attr("href", _href + '/x.pdf')
    $('#pdf_modal_button').attr("download", true)
    $('#pdf_modal_button').attr("target", "_blank")
```

it alters the link to download="true"

```
<a type="button" id="pdf_modal_button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/download/x.pdf" download="true" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

This causes the browser to open the pdf in a new tab and displays it, instead of just downloading.

Question is, how do I get it to just have a download attribute, and not download="true"

Setting the url in the download attribute doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like an empty string is what I wanted, figured it out from copying the element through chromium.

```
var _href = $('#pdf_modal_button').attr("href");
$('#pdf_modal_button').attr("href", _href + '/x.pdf')
$('#pdf_modal_button').attr("download", "")
$('#pdf_modal_button').attr("target", "_blank")
```

generates

```
<a type="button" id="pdf_modal_button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/download/x.pdf" download target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: is this an answer ?

Comment: it would still open the file in a new window

Comment: Yes, it opens it in a new window, downloads it, and then closes the window, rather than keeping it open. Setting it to true opens and displays it in a new window.

Comment: so you want it to be opened in a new window but then closed after it downloads? if that is it then its ok.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting it to true when you call

`$('#pdf_modal_button').attr("download", true)`

Try replacing true with the download link

`$('#pdf_modal_button').attr("download", "x.pdf")`